# Seaborn FacetGrid plots are empty if any of the sub-plots have no data

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset that I want to plot with FacetGrids using the seaborn library.  The problem is my data is "sparse"; some of the individual subplots don't exist (ie. there are zero data points).  I would like those cells to either not show up, or just show up and be blank, but still see the subplots that have data.  Here's a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d'],
    data=[[1,1,1,4],[1,2,2,8],[2,1,2,12],[2,1,3,14]])
print df
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='a', row='b', hue='c')
g.map(plt.scatter, 'c', 'd', marker='o')
```

Unfortunately, when I plot this, I just get four empty plots instead of 3 filled plots and one empty one.  If I change the last row of data to [2,2,3,14] instead, then all four plots appear as expected.  Is this a bug in seaborn?  Can I work around it somehow?

Comment: There must be something else going on. This works as expected for me.

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? This sounds like a bug on versions < 1.4. I'd try upgrading, otherwise you'll have to set the axis limits manually.

Comment: This is matplotlib 1.3.1-1ubuntu5 from my ubuntu install.  But the workaround of setting xlim and ylim manually works!  Thanks!

Comment: This works as expected for me also (3 filled, 1 empty plot). Voting to close as no longer reproducible.